# How to simultaneously process multiple files using spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am receiving file names from a Kafka topic. When I receive a file name.

I am doing following things now

1. Download file on local machine.
2. Start a satandalone spark job on that machine
3. I am running 10 such jobs on a single machine (64GB RAM)

I have Multiple Kafka Topics as well for each topic above process is being run on different machines.

### Now I am facing some problems

1. When a kafka topic is empty, machine allocated to that topic remains idle, while other machines have too much to do.
2. When I try to create a spark cluster of all machines, I Couldn't do that because the I have to download file first and that file is not local to all machines because I am not putting file into distributed file system(Hadoop). Is there a solution to this problem?

Can I create a better solution so that my machines are not idle and they are sharing workload from multiple Kafka topics?

Comment: Hi, did you try to use file stream as a source for your data ? I mean, does each directory contain all files Kafka topics send you ? What is the frequency of files creation (if low, it may not worth to keep a streaming cluster for a whole day) ? More information, if you aren't aware of file streams input: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources

Comment: Yes, each directory contains files in kafka topic. When a file is created its name is sent to kafka topic for processing. Frequency is 5-6 files per second for each topic and file size is < 150MB compressed.

Comment: Thanks. Did you try to implement the pipeline with directories as input for the stream (see the link of my 1st question) ? IMO it seems much more human-friendly - especially if Kafka generates the files so frequently (you won't waste cluster resources) and, except file name that Spark can find itself, doesn't provide any information needed in the processing. What do you think ? I forgot or misunderstood something ?

Comment: I did not try this. I have a question first, if I try this, I can process a directory on a single spark machine. right? Will this work for a spark cluster? And File Source will remove Kafka from the picture but Again if directory is consumed spark machines will be idle while there may be files in other directories.

Comment: It should work in the cluster. For "idle" that's the point. If you have a directory like /main_dir/dir_topic_1, /main_dir/dir_topic_2 and so on, you should be able to use a wildcard /main_dir/* as a source to read all nested files. With that the nodes won't be idle. You simply can try it in your localhost by imitating your directory tree and writing simple Structured Streaming pipeline. It'll give you an idea. From there it's only a small step to deploy it on distributed environment and test.

Comment: Thanks @bartosz25. I will give it a try